# Looking for a way to scrape urls from a page and output it to a text file

Tags: perl, vbscript

I am looking for a way to scrape URLS from a web page and output it to a text file. 
E.g if a page contains multiple `http://example.com/article`  I want to grab both these URLS and output it to a text file.

Comment: And what did you discover when you tried searching for that on this site?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

Example code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get('http://example.com/example');
foreach my $link ($mech->find_all_links()) {
    say $link->url_abs();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aSimpleLinkExtor):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::SimpleLinkExtor;

my $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new();
$extor->parse_url('http://example.com/article');
my @links = $extor->absolute_links();
```